# Kivy APP not working in background when application is switched(Android)

Tags: python, android, kivy

I have written a basic kivy code where my app visits a website every minute and display the necessary fetched data.
It works fine in my pc but when I deployed it on android app stops working when it is in background.
Therefore notifications are not displayed by my app.
here is the log which appeared when I pressed home button.

```
09-28 19:45:40.954  27008   27008   org.app.stockapp    V   PythonActivity  onPause()
09-28 19:45:40.954  27008   27008   org.app.stockapp    V   SDL onPause()
09-28 19:45:40.954  27008   27008   org.app.stockapp    V   SDL nativePause()
09-28 19:45:40.997  27008   27008   org.app.stockapp    V   SDL surfaceDestroyed()
09-28 19:45:41.055  27008   27008   org.app.stockapp    V   SDL onWindowFocusChanged(): false
```

and here is the log obtained after re-opening the app.

```
09-28 19:52:55.784  27008   27008   org.app.stockapp    V   PythonActivity  onResume()
09-28 19:52:55.784  27008   27008   org.app.stockapp    V   SDL onResume()
09-28 19:52:55.823  27008   27008   org.app.stockapp    V   SDL surfaceCreated()
09-28 19:52:55.823  27008   27008   org.app.stockapp    V   SDL surfaceChanged()
09-28 19:52:55.823  27008   27008   org.app.stockapp    V   SDL pixel format RGB_565
09-28 19:52:55.823  27008   27008   org.app.stockapp    V   SDL Window size: 1080x2094
09-28 19:52:55.824  27008   27008   org.app.stockapp    V   SDL Device size: 1080x2160
09-28 19:52:55.844  27008   27008   org.app.stockapp    V   SDL onWindowFocusChanged(): true
09-28 19:52:55.844  27008   27008   org.app.stockapp    V   SDL nativeResume()
```

Is there any way by which I can allow my app to run in background and send notification while running in background.
Don't worry about android killing app.

I found some solutions but none of them worked.

Comment: You can't have your app run in the background, but you can use an android service that constantly runs.

Comment: @inclement how? can you assist?

Comment: Have a look at the [python-for-android documentation](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/services/#service-creation).

Comment: @JohnAnderson The explanation is difficult to understand and I am finding difficulty to follow